# Exaile doesn't add songs to the queue

Tags: 10.10, sound, mp3, mp3-player, exaile

I've just upgraded from 10.04 and I have Exaile as my main player.

Anyway, when I double click a .mp3 file it opens okay. But in 10.04, if I clicked another, Exaile would push it in my playlist and that file would be the next to play. However, now in 10.10, if Exaile is already open then it doesn't add the .mp3 once I double click on it and as a result I can't seem to progressively add more files to be played, so the playlist has to be created at once, which really doesn't suit my needs.

Any way to fix this? And if there isn't, what's a good alternative on gnome?

Comment: Which version of exaile are you using? If you are looking for alternatively try banshee or gmusicbrowser.

Answer (score 1):

I think i found it!

I've noticed the same problem, although I've switched to [audacious](http://g-scripts.sourceforge.net/) a few months ago.
It's a quite interesting bug though, so i thought i should search a bit... :-)

I ran exaile with '--debug' and found the problem is already reported as bug [**#601235**](https://bugs.launchpad.net/exaile/+bug/601235)
(https://bugs.launchpad.net/exaile/+bug/601235)

There's a fix committed right now, but not yet released.

The do-it-yourself solution is quite easy though. It's given in the following link:

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~exaile-devel/exaile/0.3.2.x/revision/3436

You should just edit **xldbus.py** with your favorite editor:

`sudo gedit /usr/lib/exaile/xl/xldbus.py`

and make line 453:

`tracks = trax.sort_tracks(['album', column], tracks,reverse=descending)`

Save, restart exaile and you're done ;-)